# chartist: y-axis labels on wrong position

Tags: javascript, charts

I use chartist to display some data. One thing I could not fix are the label positions on the y-Axis. They are displayed on top of the cell, so it looks like they belong to the next grid line above, while they should be bottom aligned in the cell.
https://tristel.org

The code is:

```
        var chart=new Chartist.Line('.ct-chart', data
    , {

      fullWidth: true,
        axisX: {
            labelInterpolationFnc: function(value, index) {
                return index % 100 === 0 ? value : null;
                }
            },
        axisY: {
            labelOffset: {
                x: -10,
                y: 0
                },
                onlyInteger: true
            },
            
    
    plugins: [
            Chartist.plugins.legend({
            })
    ]});
```

Anyone who had this problem before?

Edit to explain:
[image: The label should be lower displayed.]

Comment: didn't get your question. Please describe more about the issue

Comment: @Parth: post edited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No solution found, problem solved by using google charts. https://developers.google.com/chart